# Alert if no messages have been received in the last 30 minutes

Tags: prometheus

I am working in a query for Prometheus. The service with the metrics is exposing the metrics endpoint and it contains a mymessagingservice_inbox_messagecount entry showing how many messages are in the Inbox MSMQ. 
I have a MSMQ Inbox and an Audit one. When a message arrives to the Inbox queue my service removes it from Inbox and moves it to the Autit one. My goal is to make a query that checks how many messages arrived to the Inbox queue in the past 30 minutes.
This is what my query looks like:

```
“mymessagingservice_inbox_messagecount{environment="prod"}[30m]”
```

When I run it, all results show 0. The fact is that the Audit queue shows one message 2 minutes ago. 
Not sure if I have the correct query or if there is another factor affecting the result. The only thing I can think is that the message was quickly picked up from the inbox queue and Prometheus did an observation to the endpoint before and after and this way the message was not recorded. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a gauge and reporting only the current number of "pending" messages in your queue. Here you have the problem that the time of the scrape is relevant - and thus will in most cases not produce what you need. Your use case sounds like the perfect example for a `counter` metric with an `increase()` function.

A counter is a metric type that is always increased and counts the total number of (for example) messages entering the queue. Then you can apply the `increase()` function to calculate the (not totally precise) increase of the value between the first and the last item in your range vector.

```
increase(mymessagingservice_inbox_messages_total{environment="prod"}[30m])
```

This means that you need to instrument your code in a way that you increase your counter as soon as a new message is put into the inbox.

For details see the docs on [counters](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) and the [increase function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase()). You could also have a look at the metrics of the rabbitmq exporter that does it exactly this way: https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter#queues---counter

When everything is setup, you can build a rule that calculates if there was no increase in the last 30 minutes with this simple condition:

```
increase(mymessagingservice_inbox_messages_total{environment="prod"}[30m]) == 0
```